# Unable to launch gatling getting error as Could not create directory gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.6.1

Tags: gatling

Getting Error AS WHILE LAUNCHING GATLING "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create directory C:\Users\RRahate\Desktop\NBLY\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.6.1-bundle\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.6.1\bin\gatling.sh\target"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bm0u.png)

Comment: First, latest Gatling is 3.7.4, please upgrade. Then, if you still experience an issue, please explain in depth the steps to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

##### Step 1:

Download gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.6.1

##### Step 2:

Past to C drive

##### Step 3:

Set GATLING_HOME Environment Variable as
[image]

And add bin folder to PATH environment variable

[image] path to bin folder